# Own test program on jenkins

Tags: html, xml, testing, jenkins

Jenkins build my project then I got the lib.so as output. 

I have my own test program for that. 
The test program generates test result that document format is XML.
I would like to display the result that is converted into HTML.
Could you please give me your idea ?
Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: are you looking for a way to display your HTML file in Jenkins or a way to generate your HTML from your XML?

Comment: Hi @LaurentBristiel Thanks for your comment. I would like to listen to both of them. I saw an article about the HTML publish plugin to display HTML file but I'm not sure that is proper plugin. And I'm thinking make javascript program to generate HTML using XML data. I would like to check it is right way.